# github actions run a job on pull request merge

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I am trying to run a job within github actions workflow with the following condition. My aim is to run the job if a pull request to develop branch is merged. However, when I merge a pull reqest to develop branch, the job is skipped. Can someone pl point me what I may be doing wrong?

```
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - main
      - test
      - feature
  workflow_dispatch:
```

and then the condition for the specific job

```
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop' && github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true }}
```

If I change the heads to base in the above if condition, its still the same result i.e. the job is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this solution](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-pull_request-workflow-when-a-pull-request-merges)

```
on:
 pull_request:
   types:
     - closed

jobs:
  if_merged:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
      echo The PR was merged
```

Also as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request), *GITHUB_REF* will be of format

> refs/pull/:prNumber/merge

If you are controlling changes to develop branch only via a PR merge, then why not just have a workflow on any PUSH to develop branch?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, @Arjun. There are other conditions I need to fulfil in the workflow. one of them I mentioned above. Another job, will run on a pull request to test branch and then another job when its merged to test branch. And then goes to main branch again, a job on pull request and another job on merge.
Thus, I need to fulfil, the specific condition i.e. run a particular job on merge to a specific branch.

Comment: creating multiple workflows is also perfectly fine instead of keeping everything in one file right?

Comment: I ended up using multiple workflows. Two for each branch, altogether 8 workflows. Thank you @Arjun. Will love to see if I can use in a single workflow, perhaps there is no option.